# Empty Form on Select Option Click

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using a bit of JQuery code to create placeholder values for browsers that don't support them natively. The code clears the forms whenever submit is triggered. Unfortunately, my pagination system is using a select dropdown menu with `onchange="this.form.submit()"` and the code does not empty the forms when this is used. How can I change the following code to work with my select pagination?

```
function _emptyFormOnSubmit( $elements )
{
  var $forms = $elements.closest( 'form' );

  $forms.submit( function()
  {
    var $this = $( this );

    // This check avoid processing more than once the same form.
    if( $this.data( 'placeHoldize.submitHandlerCalled' ) ) {
      return;
    }

    $this.find( '.placeholder-visible' )
       .val( '' )
       .data( 'placeHoldize.submitHandlerCalled', true );
  } );

  return true;
}
```

Comment: the values should get cleared using your submit handler, not clear what isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will work :

```
 var $forms = $elements.closest( 'form' );
 $forms.find('select[onchange="this.form.submit()"]'.change(function(){
       $forms.submit();
 })
 $forms.submit( function()
```

it's like your mixing inline attribute event and JQuery event which are based on event handler and are not well connected with inline attribute event.

Maybe (better) in your select onchange you can write :

```
  $(this).closest("form").submit()
```

Comment: Hmm. Neither one of these worked for me. I'm so confused as to why this isn't working.

Comment: I used `$(this).closest('form').submit()` and its working now. Thanks!